# Kotlin, cant match regex patters

Tags: regex, kotlin

Been trying for hours to get this simple validation to work.
It seems whatever i try to check, results are inconsistent..

```
    fun validatePassword(password: Password): Boolean {
    val noUpper = "(?=.*[A-Z])".toRegex()
    val noLower = "(?=.*[a-z])".toRegex()
    val noDigit = "(?=.*\\d)".toRegex()

    when {
        !password.newPassword.matches(noUpper) -> {
            throw WebApplicationException("Password missing uppercase letter")
        }
        !password.newPassword.matches(noLower) -> {
            throw WebApplicationException("Password missing digit")
        }
        !password.newPassword.matches(noDigit) -> {
            throw WebApplicationException("Password missing lowercase letter")
        }
        else -> return true
    }
}
```

Im not too good with regex..
how do i get these to check properly agains the errors shown here?

Thank you

Comment: I think you've got the noLower matches regex printing the "missing digit" message and the noDigit regex printing the "missing lowercase" message.  Perhaps if you pair those up appropriately you'll be fine.  I would prefer returning a message over throwing an exception.  I don't like using exceptions to express control flow.  They ought to be exceptional.

Comment: Please provide feedback if you need more help with this.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew you are correct, i was using wrong matching function. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`matches()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/matches.html) method requires a full string match, and your regexps only match an empty location followed with any 0+ chars other than line break chars followed with either an upper- or lowercase letters or a digit. You need to match and consume the whole string.

One fix is to modify just the regexps and use the rest of code as is:

```
val noUpper = "(?s)[^A-Z]*[A-Z].*".toRegex()
val noLower = "(?s)[^a-z]*[a-z].*".toRegex()
val noDigit = "(?s)\\D*\\d.*".toRegex()
```

Or, use [`find()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/-regex/find.html) (that allows partial matches inside longer strings) with a bit simpler regexes:

```
val noUpper = "[A-Z]".toRegex()
val noLower = "[a-z]".toRegex()
val noDigit = "\\d".toRegex()
```

and then

```
when {
    noUpper.find(password) == null -> {
        throw WebApplicationException("Password missing uppercase letter")
    }
    noLower.find(password) == null -> {
        throw WebApplicationException("Password missing digit")
    }
    noDigit.find(password) == null -> {
        throw WebApplicationException("Password missing lowercase letter")
    }
    else -> return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it can work for me :

```
fun validPassword(password:String):Boolean {
    val passwordPattern= "^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%^&+=])(? 
       =\\S+$).{8,}$"


    val pattern = Pattern.compile(passwordPattern)
    if(pattern.matcher(password).matches()){
    
        return true

    }
    
    return false
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation for your code rather than posting code only. Additional explanation will be more helpful.

Comment: I wrote a whole pattern in my code that if the whole pattern was completely correct it returned true, in addition in my code I wanted to check the whole string, so I used `matches` because `matches` check the whole of the string.
 But in Wiktor Stribiżew's answer because of checking the substring should use `find` method .  "find" can recognize a substring instead of the whole string.